# Add 3 secs to a specific format time using R

Tags: html, r, time

I have would like to add 3 seconds to a specific time format.
The original format is like this:

```
"2017-04-22T06:19:10.000Z", "2017-04-22T06:19:11.000Z", 
"2017-04-22T06:19:12.000Z", "2017-04-22T06:19:13.000Z", ... .
```

This is a character vector so at the forst step I need to convert it as time (maybe as.POSIXlt) but I loss the seconds:

```
> as.POSIXlt("2017-04-22T06:19:10.000Z", tz = "Europe/London")
[1] "2017-04-22 BST"
```

I tried also  the following command but I

```
> as.Date("2017-04-22T06:19:10.000Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz = "Europe/London")
[1] NA
```

What's wrong?

Tnx

Comment: Try using `strptime()` instead? `strptime("2017-04-22T06:19:10.000Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz = "Europe/London")`

Answer (score 1):

You need the format in your `as.POSIXlt` call. If you exclude the milliseconds,  `as.POSIXlt` will ignore it. Then, simply add `+3`:

Without +3:

```
as.POSIXlt("2017-04-22T06:19:10.000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz = "Europe/London")
[1] "2017-04-22 06:19:10 BST"
```

With +3

```
    as.POSIXlt("2017-04-22T06:19:10.000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz = "Europe/London") +3
[1] "2017-04-22 06:19:13 BST"
```

Comment: No need to ignore the milliseconds. `options(digits.secs = 3); as.POSIXct("2017-04-22T06:19:10.001Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ",tz = "Europe/London") + 3`

Comment: @d.b Oh, yes. I wasn't clear. I was simply saying that if your ignore them, you will get seconds as the smallest time unit. I tough OP was interested only in seconds because he uses `:%S` in his example. If he wants to add 3 seconds and keep the millisecond information, `:%OSZ` works

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms("2017-04-22T06:19:10.000Z", tz = "Europe/London")
```